How to make a function only accept an object of a class that implements an interface?
I've created an interface CanDo that defines one property someProperty. The interface is used to implement composition (classes implementing this interface should be used as parameter for doSomething()).
interface CanDo {
  someProperty;
}

function doSomething(arg: CanDo) {
 callOtherFunction(arg.someProperty);
}

class Class1 implements CanDo {
  someProperty;
}

class Class2 {
  someProperty;
}

const object1 = new Class1();
const object2 = new Class2();

doSomething(object1); //should work
doSomething(object2); //shouldn't work


The problem right now is that I can call doSomething() on both objects (since both define someProperty), but I only want it to be possible for objects of Class1.
How could I achieve this?

Does this answer your question? Avoid confusing 2 different ID types

You can't. An implements clause has no effect on the type of the class instance, and there's no metadata about it. Class2 does implement CanDo whether or not it's declared to. You need to distinguish things structurally if you care about distinguishing them. Perhaps as this playground link shows. Does that fully address the question? if so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?
